# Odd behaviour in replace()

Tags: r

I have a set of environmental data (env_PLI), where one variable is season_year. The two values for that variable are "autumn 2016" and "summer 2017". For an analysis, I need to change the variable from character to numeric, so I tried to change it so that the levels would be just 2016 and 2017 instead. However, the code

```
env_PLI$season_year <- replace(env_PLI$season_year,
                       c("autumn 2016", "summer 2017"), c(2016, 2017))
```

gives me the error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, season_year, value = c("autumn 2016",  : 
  replacement has 52 rows, data has 50
```

I tried googling it, but there results were less than helpful, since they mostly seemed to say that the variable needs to be created before using replace(), but in my case I'm using it on an existing variable. What else am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a vector `season_year <- c("A", "autumn 2016", "summer 2017")` the call

```
replace(season_year, c("autumn 2016", "summer 2017"), c(2016, 2017))
```

results in

```
#                                   autumn 2016   summer 2017 
# "A" "autumn 2016" "summer 2017"        "2016"        "2017"
```

When you look at what `replace` does

```
function (x, list, values) 
{
    x[list] <- values
    x
}
```

you might spot your mistake: you append two entries to your vector. That's why the error "replacement has 52 rows, data has 50" (in a dataframe there must be equally many entries in every column).

Try `%in%` instead

```
replace(season_year, season_year %in% c("autumn 2016", "summer 2017"), c(2016, 2017))
#[1] "A"    "2016" "2017"
```

**note**

This approach works for the dummy vector above. In case in does not work for your data 1) consider to give a minimal reproducible example and 2) simply try

```
env_PLI$season_year[env_PLI$season_year == "autumn 2016"] <- "2016"
env_PLI$season_year[env_PLI$season_year == "autumn 2017"] <- "2017"
```

Or try

```
env_PLI$season_year <- gsub("(autumn|summer)\\s+", "", env_PLI$season_year)
# similar to @Moody_Mudskipper's second solution
```

Thanks to @RichardTelford and @Duckmayr.

Comment: This solution will fail with `season_year <- c("A", "autumn 2016", "summer 2017", "summer 2017") `. `plyr::mapvalues` is a direct replacement for the original code.

Comment: @RichardTelford Good point. Was not aware of `plyr::mapvalues`. Why not turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of different options you could consider :

```
readr::parse_number(c("autumn 2016", "summer 2017"))
# [1] 2016 2017
gsub("\\D","",c("autumn 2016", "summer 2017")) # could be wrapped into as.numeric
# [1] "2016" "2017"
```

Answer (score 1):

Marcus explained why you have a problem with `replace` but the solution he gave will fail in some circumstances.

There are several solutions to changing values in a vector.

```
season_year <- c("A", "autumn 2016", "summer 2017", "summer 2017")
```

`plyr::mapvalues` is a direct replacement for your original code. I find this most useful when I have the from and to vectors in a data.frame, like a dictionary.

```
plyr::mapvalues(season_year, from = c("autumn 2016", "summer 2017"), to = c(2016, 2017))
[1] "A"    "2016" "2017" "2017"
```

`dplyr::recode` takes pairs of old and new values.

```
dplyr::recode(season_year, "autumn 2016" = "2016", "summer 2017" = "2017")
[1] "A"    "2016" "2017" "2017"
```

You could use regular expressions to extract the year. `\\d{4}` looks for a sequence of four digits. Regular expressions are very powerful when the data need cleaning.

```
gsub(pattern = ".*(\\d{4})", replacement = "\\1", season_year)
[1] "A"    "2016" "2017" "2017"
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I've misinterpreted your question.

```
library(tidyverse)
dummydf<-data.frame(Id=c(1,2),Period=c("autumn 2006","spring 2007"))
#Change to character
dummydf %>% 
  mutate(Period=as.character(Period))
#Back to numeric
dummydf %>% 
  mutate(Period=as.numeric(Period))
```

## Or Maybe this

```
dummydf$Period %>% 
str_replace_all("autumn","")
```